# VBScript password change email error

Tags: vbscript

Apologies in advance for any incorrect terminology (I am a PC Tech, not a developer/programmer).

We have a VBScript running in one of our servers to send an email notice to users that their Windows password will expire and they need to change it. The script is as follows:

```
       *******************Begin Code*****
    on error resume next
    Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
    Const E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND = &h8000500D
    Const ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND = .000000100
    Const SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400
    strDomainDN = "DomainNameHere" 'Domain name here - both Netbios and DNS style names should work 
    ReminderAge = 10 'Days before the reminders start being sent
    'strbody - Body of the message being sent
    strbody = "This message is a reminder that your password will be expiring soon." & vbcrlf
    strbody = strbody & "Please change your network password before the date listed above to avoid being locked out of the system." & vbcrlf
    strbody = strbody & "If you need instructions on how to change your password please contact:" & vbcrlf
    strbody = strbody & "the IT Department" & vbcrlf
    strbody = strbody & vbcrlf & "Thank you," & vbcrlf
    strbody = strbody & "IT Department"

    'create logfile
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strScriptPath = objfso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    strLogName = TwoDigits(Year(now)) & TwoDigits(Month(now)) & TwoDigits(Day(now)) & TwoDigits(Hour(now)) & TwoDigits(Minute(now)) & 
    TwoDigits(Second(now)) & ".txt"
    strLogFile = strScriptPath & "Logs\" & StrLogName
    Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strLogFile,1)
    objLogfile.Writeline "Email Password Check Script started: " & Now
    Dim rootDSE,domainObject
    Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
    Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")
    DomainContainer = rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
    Set fs = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
    conn.Open "ADs Provider"
    numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
    'LDAP string to only find user accounts with mailboxes
    ldapStr = "<LDAP://" & DomainContainer & ">;(& (mailnickname=*) (| 
    (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!(homeMDB=*))(!(msExchHomeServerName=*)))(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(homeMDB=*)(msExchHomeServerName=*))) ));adspath;subtree"
    Set rs = conn.Execute(ldapStr)
    While Not rs.EOF
    Set oUser = GetObject (rs.Fields(0).Value)
    dtmValue = oUser.PasswordLastChanged
    If Err.Number = E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND Then
    whenpasswordexpires = "The password has never been set."
    else
    whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
    end if
    daysb4expire = Int(whenPasswordExpires - Now)
    'write user info to logfile
    objLogfile.Writeline "-----------------------------------------"
    objLogfile.Writeline "SAM Acct: " & oUser.SamAccountName
    objLogfile.Writeline "Disp Name: " & oUser.displayName
    objLogfile.Writeline "UPN: " & oUser.userprincipalname
    objLogfile.Writeline "PW Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged
    objLogfile.Writeline "PW Expires: " & whenPasswordExpires
    dblMaxPwdNano = Abs(MaxPwdAge.HighPart * 2^32 + MaxPwdAge.LowPart)
    dblMaxPwdSecs = dblMaxPwdNano * ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND
    dblMaxPwdDays = Int(dblMaxPwdSecs / SECONDS_IN_DAY)
    objLogfile.Writeline "The password will expire on " & _
    DateValue(dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays) & " (" & _
    Int((dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays) - Now) & " days from today)."
    if daysb4expire < ReminderAge and daysb4expire > 0 then
    objLogfile.Writeline "Expiring soon - sending eMail"
    objLogfile.Writeline "*****************************"
    strNoteMessage = "Dear " & oUser.displayName & "," & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
    strNoteMessage = strNoteMessage & "Your Network password will expire on " & _
    DateValue(dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays) & " (" & _
    Int((dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays) - Now) & " days from today)." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf

    Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objEmail.From = "me@myCompany.com" 'Your From Address
    objEmail.To = oUser.userprincipalname
    objEmail.Subject = "Network Password Expiration Notice" 'Message subject
    objEmail.TextBody = strNoteMessage & strBody
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = 

    "YOUREXCHANGE.SERVER.DomainName.COM" ' Your mailserver here
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
    'objEmail.Send 'commented out right now---so you won't send out the email.
    End If
    set whenpasswordexpires = nothing
    err.clear
    rs.MoveNext
    Wend
    Set oUser = Nothing
    Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
    Set oDomain = Nothing
    Logfile.Close
    Function TwoDigits(t)
    TwoDigits = Right("00" & t,2)
    End Function
    WScript.quit
```

Obviously I removed our info from the script for this post.

The errors are that:

1. It does not send an email everyday if the user does not change their password for a few days. It sends them randomly.
2. A few random users, if they have not changed their password, around the 5th or 6th day will start getting hundreds of thousands of emails in just a few seconds, completely locking down Outlook on their computer. If they change the password they stop getting them (obviously).

Is there something I'm missing or need to remove from this script to get it to at least stop sending so many emails at once?

Thank you.

Comment: If the loop is controlled by the results of the LDAP lookup, I would check to see what values it is returning as a part of my troubleshooting.

Comment: Pardon my inexperience but I'm not sure what you mean by "check to see what values it is returning". Is there some sort of event log that the script creates in the server every time it runs?

Comment: The code is writing to the "\Logs" folder each time the application is called.  You should find this folder at the same folder level as this script.

Comment: I found the history in the task scheduler (I guess that's where it's running from). There are quite a few errors but it's all the same error. Start Task Failed, event ID 101. Doesn't that just mean that the scrpit failed to run at that particular time? There are some days that it will run with no errors but some that it will get errors and fail to run and be terminated. I have no idea what is causing those errors.

Comment: Track down what that eventid is.  You may have to compare the log file to the server's application log file to gather more information about what is happening.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured that out. It was set to stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days and not to start a new instance. I changed it to 1 day and stop the existing instance. Now I just need to figure out why users are getting so many emails at once.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas to help you track down the problem.

1. Only have `on error resume next` before the command that needs it `oUser.PasswordLastChanged`, after that line `on error goto 0` Then run the script manually and you'll have a better chance of finding some statement that is failing. `update - should store the value in a variable and use`
2. Get consistent with what variables are for. `whenpasswordexpires` is set to text in one part of the `if err.number` and a date in the other. It's then used as a date to calculate days and finally `set whenpasswordexpires = nothing` treats it like an object. This could mean some of your if statements are erroring and just going to the next line, instead of skipping the if - so people might be getting mailed when they shouldn't.
3. Consider calculating a date to pass to the LDAP query and only return people to be emailed - instead of going through all users all the time
4. (without ever having much to do with LDAP queries) I think your current query simplifies down to `ldapStr = "<LDAP://" & DomainContainer & ">;(& (mailnickname=*)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user));adspath;subtree"` all the ors and ands with homeMDB and msExchHomeServerName would seem to mean any combination is included. It's probably worth running your query in an LDAP explorer tool to check you're really getting what you want.
5. LDAP often has a limit of the number of records returned, so you might be erroring all the time because you get more than 1000 (typical) records returned. This can be worked around by getting data in smaller pages (say 250).
6. Logging to a new file each time may hide issues from you, e.g if the task is restarted by scheduler. Much easier to diagnose if there is just one log per day. You also don't close the log file correctly - should be objLogFile.Close (not logfile.Close). You aren't putting the log in a subdirectory of the scripts folder (e.g. scripts & scripts\logs) but at the same level (e.g. scripts & scriptsLogs)
7. The logfile not objLogFile issue highlights why it is best to put Option Explicit at the top of your code. This means you have to dim every variable that you use, which can be a pain to do, but ensures that you don't have typos in your variable names which can cause you massive headaches.
8. The WScript.Quit is the very last line, so won't do anything - the codes about to finish anyway. If you ever want to abort the execution of script, the WScript.Quit needs to where you want to abort from - normally within some `if` statement.
9. There are a number of repeated calculations... days, dtmValue + dblMaxPwdDays, etc. I just mention this as it makes the code harder to read and therefore harder to understand what might be wrong.

All that said, I've probably made too many comments now for you to really comprehend without me just making the changes and posting updated script for you to try.

See if this version runs error free for you...

---

```
option explicit 

Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
Const E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND = &h8000500D
Const ONE_HUNDRED_NANOSECOND = .000000100
Const SECONDS_IN_DAY = 86400

Dim strDomainDN, strBody, strNoteMessage
Dim objFSO, objLogFile, objEmail
Dim strScriptPath, strLogName, strLogFile

strDomainDN = "DomainNameHere" 'Domain name here - both Netbios and DNS style names should work 
Const ReminderAge = 10 'Days before the reminders start being sent
'strbody - Body of the message being sent
strbody = "This message is a reminder that your password will be expiring soon." & vbcrlf
strbody = strbody & "Please change your network password before the date listed above to avoid being locked out of the system." & vbcrlf
strbody = strbody & "If you need instructions on how to change your password please contact:" & vbcrlf
strbody = strbody & "the IT Department" & vbcrlf
strbody = strbody & vbcrlf & "Thank you," & vbcrlf
strbody = strbody & "IT Department"

'create logfile
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strScriptPath = objfso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
strLogName = TwoDigits(Year(now)) & TwoDigits(Month(now)) & TwoDigits(Day(now)) & ".txt"
strLogFile = strScriptPath & "Logs\" & StrLogName
Set objLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLogFile, 8, True)
objLogFile.Writeline "Email Password Check Script started: " & Now

Dim rootDSE, oDomain, DomainContainer
Dim maxPwdAge, numDays
Dim conn, command
Dim ldapStr
Dim rs, oUser, passwordChanged, whenPasswordExpires, daysb4expire

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")
DomainContainer = rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
conn.Provider = "ADSDSOObject"
conn.Open "ADs Provider"
Set command.ActiveConnection = conn
command.Properties("Page Size") = 250
numDays = ABS(CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(864000000000))

'LDAP string to only find user accounts with mailboxes
Dim dteCnv, sec1601, strExpireDate, strRemindDate
dteCnv = DateAdd("d", -numDays, Now)                             
sec1601 = DateDiff("s","1/1/1601",dteCnv)                              
strExpireDate = CStr(sec1601) & "0000000"                              

dteCnv = DateAdd("d", ReminderAge - numDays, Now)                             
sec1601 = DateDiff("s","1/1/1601",dteCnv)                              
strRemindDate = CStr(sec1601) & "0000000"                              

ldapStr = "<LDAP://" & DomainContainer & ">;(& (mailnickname=*)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(pwdLastSet>=" & strExpireDate & ")(pwdLastSet<=" & strRemindDate & "));adspath;subtree"
command.CommandText = ldapStr
Set rs = command.Execute
While Not rs.EOF
    Set oUser = GetObject (rs.Fields(0).Value)
    on error resume next
    passwordChanged = oUser.PasswordLastChanged
    If Err.Number = E_ADS_PROPERTY_NOT_FOUND Then
        passwordChanged = "Never"
        whenPasswordExpires = Now
    elseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
        passwordChanged = "Unknown - " & Err.Description
        whenPasswordExpires = Now
    else
        whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, passwordChanged)
    end if
    on error goto 0
    daysb4expire = Int(whenPasswordExpires - Now)

    'write user info to logfile
    objLogFile.Writeline "-----------------------------------------"
    objLogFile.Writeline "SAM Acct: " & oUser.SamAccountName
    objLogFile.Writeline "Disp Name: " & oUser.displayName
    objLogFile.Writeline "UPN: " & oUser.userprincipalname
    objLogFile.Writeline "PW Changed: " & passwordChanged
    objLogFile.Writeline "PW Expires: " & whenPasswordExpires

    objLogFile.Writeline "The password will expire on " & whenPasswordExpires & " (" & daysb4expire & " days from today)."

    if daysb4expire <= ReminderAge and daysb4expire > 0 then
        objLogFile.Writeline "Expiring soon - sending eMail"
        objLogFile.Writeline "*****************************"
        strNoteMessage = "Dear " & oUser.displayName & "," & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
        strNoteMessage = strNoteMessage & "Your Network password will expire on " & whenPasswordExpires & " (" & daysb4expire & " days from today)." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf

        Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objEmail.From = "me@myCompany.com" 'Your From Address
        objEmail.To = oUser.userprincipalname
        objEmail.Subject = "Network Password Expiration Notice" 'Message subject
        objEmail.TextBody = strNoteMessage & strBody
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "YOUREXCHANGE.SERVER.DomainName.COM" ' Your mailserver here
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        objEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
        'objEmail.Send 'commented out right now---so you won't send out the email.
    End If

    err.clear
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
Set oUser = Nothing
Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
Set oDomain = Nothing
objLogFile.Writeline "Email Password Check completed: " & Now & vbcrlf & vbcrlf
objLogFile.Close


Function TwoDigits(t)
    TwoDigits = Right("00" & t,2)
End Function
```

---

Comment: Ok, I have removed the `on error resume next`. I have also removed the `WScript.Quit` since it seems to be the wrong syntax and it wasn't actually quitting the script. I have added a timeout to the very end of the script `WScript.Timeout = 120` after `End Function`. I don't know how fast VBScripts run, if they run the entire script in a matter of seconds and everyone who is supposed to receive an email gets one. I know next to nothing about VBScripts so everything I am trying to fix I am also learning about in the process. Please let me know if you think these additions will work. Thank you.

Comment: WScript.Timeout should be near the top of your code to have any benefit, but I don't think that would help much anyway, doing this takes as long as it takes... making the query smarter will save time. See my edits above

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help on this matter. I am going to test it and let you know how it works.